# How to set Windows to use an external RADIUS server for user authentication to share folder?

Tags: windows, radius, share

Is it possible and if so how, to make users use an external [RADIUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) server to connect to Windows shares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this can be done. Windows itself only uses AD to authorize and authenticate users. The only way that I think this could be done would be if you had another system using Kerberos, that could use RADIUS as the user backend, and then make a trust between your Windows AD and the Kerberos domain. I don't know if such a product exists.

Comment: It may be possible by using samba server as slave with windows AD

Comment: It does seem that you can enable Samba to do authentication using RADIUS as the backend if you enable clear-text passwords. But then those aren't Windows shares, are they - they're Linux shares served by Samba.

Comment: hm. http://support.mof.go.th/radius_windows.html. it seems possible to user radius with AD. and setup raidiues server. Port forward local radius port to external server and make correct policy on remote.

Comment: Yes, I know how to set up RADIUS (IAS) to use AD as a backend; that's what IAS is for. You can't use IAS for authenticating users for file-sharing in Windows, it's only for remote access.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by Windows Shares you want something CIFS compatible...

In which case the best route might be to start a Samba server and configure it to use RADIUS Auth, which is well supported by smbd.